# How to change the color of WordPress navigation on hover

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I am developing a website using a thrive theme on WordPress. I am trying to change the on hover color on the blog page specifically because it's built differently from the other pages.

Presently on hover it goes white from black which isn't what I am trying to achieve.

I searched online and saw some articles and code snippets which have brought me to trying this

```
header nav ul li a : hover {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    position: relative;
}

header nav > ul.menu > li > a : hover {
    color: #373737;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

I have applied `: hover` to the navigation element to try to change the color on hover, but it doesn't work.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here? The site is at

```
http://stefanjames.com/blog/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces around the pseudoclass `:` selector in your CSS, so that it reads:

`header nav > ul.menu > li > a:hover`

Comment: really omg, i ws almost going crazy, thanks give sm minutes i will like ur reply

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax wasn't perfect. There should be no spaces between your `:` and the pseudo selector property.

```
header nav > ul.menu > li > a : hover
```

should become

```
header nav > ul.menu > li > a:hover
```

I had a look at the site, you would need the following added to your CSS file:

```
header nav > ul.menu > li > a:hover {
  color: #373737;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-navigation ul li a:hover{color:red;}
```

Comment: Can you add more detail to your answer, please? That would make it easier to understand your solution. Thanks! :)